# If a value in one column matches the value in another column, copy the name in the cell next to the match

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

If the number in Column B has a match in Column H, then I want to copy the representatives name in Column G to Column C next to the Match.

Here's an example in Google Sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WkSl7kyODra5LULxtNXA6pcBEEkEh86_BLjoGYCrgRA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Enter the below formula in cell `C2` and drag it down,

```
=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(B2,H:H,0),1)
```